# Subquery in SQL Server issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm stuck right now...

I've got 4 types of invoices which require different selected fields...

Now I'm trying something like...

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE type ='inv') THEN
            (SELECT a,b,c FROM invoices)

WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE type ='credit') THEN
            (SELECT d,e,f FROM invoices)
end
from invoices
```

This is not working as you can imagine...

I'm getting:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Does any one have any idea of how to proceed with something like this? I'm completely lost....

Comment: CASE is not for control of flow, use IF EXISTS / ELSE instead.

Comment: Hi alex, can you give me a bit more detail please?

Answer (score 4):

You can't put a subquery as a result of a CASE WHEN instruction. Try, one of these:

```
SELECT  case [type]
            when 'inv'    then a
            when 'credit' then d        
            else 0
        end
        ,
        case [type]
            when 'inv'    then b
            when 'credit' then e        
            else 0
        end
        ,
        case [type]
            when 'inv'    then c
            when 'credit' then f
            else 0
        end
from invoices
```

or

```
select  a, b, c
from    invoices
where   [type] = 'inv'
union
select  d, e, f
from    invoices
where   [type] = 'credit'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you want, columns a, b and c when type ='inv', or columns d, e, f when type ='credit':

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM invoices WHERE type ='inv'
UNION ALL
SELECT d,e,f FROM invoices WHERE type ='credit'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also return all fields ignoring or setting the invalid fields for the record to null.

```
SELECT 
    a=CASE WHEN Type='inv' THEN a ELSE NULL END,
    b=CASE WHEN Type='inv' THEN b ELSE NULL END,
    c=CASE WHEN Type='inv' THEN c ELSE NULL END,
    d=CASE WHEN Type='credit' THEN d ELSE NULL END,
    e=CASE WHEN Type='credit' THEN e ELSE NULL END,
    f=CASE WHEN Type='credit' THEN f ELSE NULL END,
FROM
    invoices
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like that:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE type ='inv')
            (SELECT a,b,c FROM invoices)

ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE type ='credit')
            (SELECT d,e,f FROM invoices)
```

Comment: This returns a column a,b,c for every type of invoice not just inv

Comment: i'm sorry but I do not agree, I've checked this out before I wrote the answer and did a recheck right now.